# replace non matches between delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex

I've have a input string:

> 12345,3244,654,ffgv,87676,988ff,87657

I'm having a difficulty to transform all terms in the string that are not five digit numbers to a constant 34567 using regular expressions. So, the output would be like this:

> 12345,34567,34567,34567,87676,34567,87657

For this, I looked at two options:

1. **negated character class**: Not useful because it does not execute directly on this expression `,[^\d{5}],`
2. **lookahead and lookbehind**: Issue here is that it doesn't include non-matched part in the result of this expression `,(?!\d{5})` or `(?<!\d{5}),` for the purpose of substitution/replace.

Once the desired expression is found, it would give a result so that one can replace non-matched part using tagged regions like `\1`, `\2`.

Is there any mechanism in regular expression tools to achieve the output as mentioned in the above example?

Edit: I really appreciate those who have answered non-regex solutions, but I would be more thankful if you provide a regex-based solution.

Comment: So, Python, JavaScript, or Perl? What language are you using?

Comment: @Сухой27: This question doesn't mention a language, and regexes are mostly language-independent. If a language tag were to be added, it should be one, and only one, that the OP mentions, somewhere...

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm sorry if Python was mis-tagged. IMHO, regular expressions were evolved from Perl. PHP is based on Perl, just like RoR on Ruby. I'm working in JavaScript with PHP backend. I'm currently restructing the website moving from heavy server side query executions to MVC framework. In PHP, I faced the same problem in PHP, but I did the work around using split function and looping about the array. Now, it is JavaScript. But a regex in Perl can be easily adapted to any language. I thought Python is a scripting sister of Perl, so I might have tagged Python along.

Comment: So you have to put `PHP` tag, one which you've missed at the beginning. btw, RoR is Ruby framework, and PHP is NOT Perl framework.

Comment: @Сухой27: The OP can add the proper tags in whenever he wishes. Just adding a language, not to mention different languages, based on assumptions is a bad idea. Neeraj: What language do you plan on using the regex in? Tag it with that language...

Comment: @Сухой27 Yes, PHP is not a framework. In general, one can say: PHP is based on Perl, Django based on Python,  RoR based on Ruby, ASP based on VBScript, Spring based on Java etc

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've re-tagged the question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this. You can use `str.split` to split the string at commas first and then for each item check if its length is greater than or equal to 5 and it contains only digits(using `str.isdigit`). Lastly combine all the items using `str.join`.

```
>>> s = '12345,3244,654,ffgv,87676,988ff,87657'
>>> ','.join(x if len(x) >= 5 and x.isdigit() else '34567' for x in s.split(','))
'12345,34567,34567,34567,87676,34567,87657'
```

Javascript version:

```
function isdigit(s){
    for(var i=0; i <s.length; i++){
       if(!(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')){
           return false;    
        }
    }
    return true;
}
arr = "12345,3244,654,ffgv,87676,988ff,87657".split(",");

for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].length < 5 || ! isdigit(arr[i])) arr[i] = '34567';
}
output = arr.join(",")
```

Comment: Apparently the OP wants to use this functionality in JavaScript. Could you possibly add a JS solution to your answer?

Comment: @Cerbrus Added a JS solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would work for value no longer than 5 alphanumeric characters:

```
(,(?!\d{5})\w{1,5})
```

if longer than 5 alphanumeric characters, then remove `5` in above expression:

```
(,(?!\d{5})\w{1,})
```

and you can replace using:

```
,34567
```

You can see a [demo on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/mO3tM6/1). Of course, there might be faster non-regex methods for specific languages as well (python, perl or JS)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: `/\b(?!\d{5})[^,]+\b/g`

- It constrains the expression between *word* boundaries (`\b`),
- Followed by a negative look-ahead for non five digit numbers (`!\d{5}`),
- Followed by any characters between `,`

```js
const expression = /\b(?!\d{5})[^,]+\b/g;
const input = '12345,3244,654,ffgv,87676,988ff,87657';
const expectedOutput = '12345,34567,34567,34567,87676,34567,87657';

const output = input.replace(expression, '34567');
console.log(output === expectedOutput, expectedOutput, output);
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses `/\b(\d{5})|(\w+)\b/g`:

- we match on boundaries (`\b`)
- our first capture group captures "good strings"
- our looser capture group gets the leftovers (bad strings)
- our `replacer()` function knows the difference

```js
const str = '12345,3244,654,ffgv,87676,988ff,87657';
const STAND_IN = '34567';

const massageString = (str) => {
    const pattern = /\b(\d{5})|(\w+)\b/g;
    const replacer = (match, goodstring, badstring) => {
        if (goodstring) {
          return goodstring;
        } else {
          return STAND_IN;
        }
    }    
    const r = str.replace(pattern,replacer);
    return r;
};

console.log( massageString(str) );
```